# Swift: Cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt32]' with an index of type 'UInt32'

Tags: swift, xcode7

This is my code snippet from swift:

```
var color_info: [UInt32] = []
var r = 0xff
var g = 0xff
var b = 0xff

r = r & 0xf0
g = g & 0xf0
b = b & 0xf0

var index_array =  UInt32(r) | (UInt32(g) << 8) | (UInt32(b) << 16)
color_info[index_array]++
```

Why can't I access the array using the variable `index_array`? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The index needs to be `Int`. Once it compiles, your code will most likely crash, because you have an empty array and try to access n-th element that does not exist.

You can pre-initialize like this:

```
var color_info = Array(count: 100, repeatedValue: UInt32(0))
```

It looks like you would require pretty large array. Perhaps there is a way to achieve your goal with different algorithm and less memory? Using dictionary might be an option (key = rgb, value = count), that would take memory only for colors that are actually present in the image as opposed to the array. I suspect that this would be pretty slow for large images, though...

Comment: OK, thanks. I will typecast it to Int.. I am new to Swift.... coming back to your one more comment that the empty array will crash, this is what I am trying to do, please let me know how I can do it in Swift... I am parsing an Image and I want to store the color information in the array. the index to array is the "rgb".  Do I need to allocate an large array? or swift has a way to expand array on the fly?

Comment: Thanks ! Let me take me look into dictionary as well.